# Filepath for Django Extending Template

Tags: python, django

Here is my template path

```
webapp/
  |__templates/
        |__frontpage/
        |     |__home.html
        |__home_base.html
```

In home.html, it has:

```
{% extends "home_base.html" %}
```

This file structure will work. However, I want to put home_base.html inside frontpage/, as this makes more sense. However, Django will report home_base.html TEMPLATE DOES NOT EXIST, if home_base.html is moved to frontpage/.

The error says it cannot find the home_base.html file under templates/ folder. Since the home_base.html is moved to frontpage/, why doesn't it search for home_base.html inside frontpage/ first? Any configurations I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following for template to be extended.

```
{% extends "frontpage/home_base.html" %}
```

Django does not have an idea where you have have moved your template. It will look for the template according to the templates path you have defined in your settings.

The [**template loader**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) will look for template in the directories defined in the [`DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#dirs) setting in the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) settings.

From the `DIRS` setting documentation:

> Directories where the engine should look for template source files, in
>   search order.

Also, if `frontpage` was an app and you had placed your template in the `frontpage` app instead of the `templates` folder, then you can set the [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#app-dirs) settings to be `True`. This will tell Django to find the templates in the individual apps also.

From the `APP_DIRS` setting documentation:

> Whether the engine should look for template source files inside
>   installed applications.